# Python - Parse float string to an integer

Tags: python, math

I want to convert a string like "0.75" into 3/4. Do python has any builtin function for this.

I know i can convert it using float("0.75") to get a float value. But I need only integer number without loosing resolution.

I can write a function like multiplying it by 100, so I will get 75/100, but still how to evaulate to 3/4. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(0.75)
Fraction(3, 4)
```

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).

One caveat: Non-binary fractions (i.e. fractions derived from [floating point numbers that cannot be represented accurately in binary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), like `0.9`) may yield surprising results unless you pass the string representation of the `float`:

```
>>> Fraction(0.9)
Fraction(8106479329266893, 9007199254740992)
>>> Fraction("0.9")
Fraction(9, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python has the [fractions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module.

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction('0.75')
Fraction(3, 4)
```